# How to build Android-Apk with unity 2021.3.2f1c1？

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I can build project with mac-OS, Windows with unity,but when I switch platform to Android, unity cause Error :
Exception: OBSOLETE - Providing Android resources in Assets/Plugins/Android/res was removed, please move your resources to an AAR or an Android Library. See "AAR plug-ins and Android Libraries" section of the Manual for more details.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckUserResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <94fa632991b24a5888314fbf454f292b>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <94fa632991b24a5888314fbf454f292b>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <94fa632991b24a5888314fbf454f292b>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <94fa632991b24a5888314fbf454f292b>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.PrepareForBuild (UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:162)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

It seems like I should build a android-aar, but what files I need？

Answer (score 1):

This Issue comes from Unity Itself.

check this thread. [Unity Issue](https://forum.unity.com/threads/exception-obsolete-providing-android-resources-in-assets-plugins-android-assets-was-removed.1171829/)

**Deleting** the "Assets" folder in "\Assets\Plugins\Android" fix it for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you have res folder under \Assets\Plugins\Android . delete that

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure to delete the "**assets.meta**" file as well as "asset" folder under "\Assets\Plugins\Android"